# RenderTransformOrigin vs CenterX and CenterY

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

When applying a transform on a control in Windows Store apps, to set the origin of the transform, I see from the documentation that you can either set `RenderTransformOrigin` on the control or set `CenterX` and `CenterY` on the transform itself.

What is the difference between the two ? When both of these are set, which of them takes precedence ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RenderTransformOrigin` is **relative**, but `CenterX` and `CenterY` are **absolute**.

Suppose you have an element with width and height of 100. Then if you set `RenderTransformOrigin = "0.5,0.5"` and `CenterX = 10` and `CenterY = 10` then the center is shifted 10 pixels in both vertical and horizontal directions from the origin point which is at [X = 100 * 0.5 = 50 , Y = 100 * 0.5 = 50].